# Connecting A Raspberry Pi to a Windows PC Using Node.js | Making a Remote GRBL Control

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, raspberry-pi

I recently got a [small 300mm bed CNC Machine](https://usa.banggood.com/3018-Pro-3-Axis-Mini-DIY-CNC-Router-Adjustable-Speed-Spindle-Motor-Wood-Engraving-Machine-Milling-Engraver-p-1463876.html?rmmds=myorder&cur_warehouse=CN) that has it's issues, which isn't really relevant, but to fix those issues I need to ask my friend. He has quite a lot of experience working with CNC Machines, but even when I screenshared the GRBL Software, he couldn't fix some problems that he said should be a simple fix, hence, the node.js app.
I would like to connect a Raspberry Pi up to the CNC Driver board, host a server on Heroku, and have him connect to the server. The server would then pick up his input, translate it into GCode, and push it to the Raspberry Pi (which would send it to the driver board). I know how to set up the server, even code it so that he can press a button and it translates to GCode, but my question is, ***how could the Raspberry Pi get the Node equivalent of a message telling it the GCode the user wants to push***? I have some experience with Node.js and have made a Chat Application, but this seems a little different.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The GRBL software didn't work... so you wrote your own using node.js?

Comment: @JoeBeck Yes, I copied some Node.js examples for sending data/gcode to a cnc machine. Didn't work as well... I also used the GCode sender that came with the cnc, didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all the answers you'll need will be [in this video](https://youtu.be/hB4Cvbtu-lA?t=658)

If you have issues with any of that, then we'll have a good reference point. Best of luck.

Comment: I actually came in contact with that video, only issue is that I didn't get any software with the CNC machine (unlike the video example).
I also contacted the seller, and they said that there isn't any files to go with it, so not sure if I should refund the machine or not.

Comment: @DivineLemon , sorry I'm a bit confused. If the link provided is the router, then no it does not include physical discs or drives loaded with the software. Instead, the software can be obtained here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ybh0xihxeco9szp/AAAt8XkxL1V_5AkwQN2K-w17a?dl=0

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it to work using that software, many thanks!!!!!

Comment: @DivineLemon , aswesome! you're very welcome. Cheers!